# Passing props from child components to main

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im learning react and now for my project I need pass props from my User component to my Main Component. I get this mistake every time i try to do it like guy on [this video](https://youtu.be/A71aqufiNtQ?t=34m44s):

```
handleSelectedUser(user){
    console.log(this.state);
  }



   render() {
      let users;

      let selectElem = this.selectElement;

    if (this.state.displayedUsers) {
      users = this.state.displayedUsers.map(function (usr) {
        return (
          <User  key={usr.contact.phone} user={usr} someInfo={this.handleSelectedUser.bind(this)}/>
          //this one throwing this mistake: "ContactsApp.js:44 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleSelectedUser' of undefined"
        );
      });
    }


    return (
      <div>
        <div className="left-column">
          <div className="users">
              <SearchUser handleEvent= {this.handleSearch.bind(this)} />
              <ul className="usersList"> {users} </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="right-column">
          <ContactDetail someInfo={this.handleSelectedUser.bind(this)} selectedUser={this.props.items[3]} /> //this element works well 
        </div>
      </div>
      );
  }
}
```

User component and ContactDetail component have the same method that adds a someInfo prop to it, but only ContactDetail works well. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

excellent choice choosing to learn React and great instructor you choose. Your problem was not the React logic itself, but you made a JavaScript mistake, an ES6 one to be exact. This is your current code:

```
if (this.state.displayedUsers) {
  users = this.state.displayedUsers.map(function (usr) {
    return (
      <User  key={usr.contact.phone} user={usr} someInfo={this.handleSelectedUser.bind(this)}/>
      //this one throwing this mistake: "ContactsApp.js:44 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleSelectedUser' of undefined"
    );
  });
}
```

Now as you can see the error you get is

```
Cannot read property 'handleSelectedUser' of undefined"
```

And how do you call it?

```
this.handleSelectedUser.bind(this)
```

That means that **undefined** in the error above is **this**

Why does that happen? When you map through an array it is a common pracitce to use an arrow function instead of an unnamed function, like this:

```
users = this.state.displayedUsers.map((usr) => {
return (
  <User  key={usr.contact.phone} user={usr} someInfo={this.handleSelectedUser.bind(this)}/>
      //this will now work
    );
});
```

Difference is that () => {has acces to **this**}, but function() {dosent have acces to **this**}

Comment: Oh thank you, master Jedi! i tried to figure it out for 2 hours but problem was sooooo easy. Honestly speaking, i`m a bit afraid of arrow functions bcs for me its hard to read them. But for now, i will start using them

Answer (score 0):

Use an `=>` instead of `function` in your map function like this

```
users = this.state.displayedUsers.map(usr => {
        return (
          <User  key={usr.contact.phone} user={usr} someInfo={this.handleSelectedUser.bind(this)}/>
        );
      });
```

**But why though?**  In short the `this` keyword is referring to the anonymous function you created inside of your map function. While the `=>` symbol make's the scope transparent so `this` would behave as you would expect.

I know that doesn't explain the entire picture but, hopefully it provides enough insight to deal with this solution. You may want to consider doing more research on this topic.

Another solution could be assigning a temporary variable to `this` like so `var self = this;` and then use `self` from there on.

P.S. The .bind() you are adding to your function is also another way to resolve this issue but, it would require some additional refactoring.